# Merge the "non-static" and "nonstatic" tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[non-static](/questions/tagged/non-static) has 80 questions, and [nonstatic](/questions/tagged/nonstatic) has 11 questions. I propose to merge them together into [non-static](/questions/tagged/non-static) as they mean the same.

Comment: This tag seems quite useless IMO... It should be retagged into `dynamic` or maybe `instance`, as it's entirely ambiguous as to whether it refers to data or the scope of a method.

Comment: I don't see it that useless, as it is specific reference for a type method or property

Comment: no, it is useless, as it's not a type of method, its the exclusion of a modifier on a method. In that case, [tag:instance-method] should be used, not 'nonstatic'.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That's your point of view, and I respect it! So, there for we shall wait and see what the rest of the community has to say about this, as well as the moderators.

Comment: Eh, non-static and dynamic don't mean the same thing, so...

Comment: Actually "dynamic" means almost nothing. At least the way it's used in many questions. "How do I choose an item from a list dynamically?", "How can I compare two dynamic values?" ... in that (common) type of question, the word can be removed entirely.</rant>

Comment: @JoachimSauer Maybe there is an expert of dynamics. `;)`

Answer (score 3):

It are only 11 questions, so I just spent one little minute on manually editing the tags. If the [nonstatic](/questions/tagged/nonstatic) isn't used anymore by end of day, it'll be removed.